# What are chances of offering my IT skillset to getting a remote I.T jobs or freelance jobs in the Philippines?

Tags: philippines, remote-locations

I am Solutions Architect working as a Technical Support Engineer in Nigeria. And I am moving to the Philippines to get a master’s degree from St. Dominic College of Asia.

Though I have DevOps skillset, however, I read that it is very hard to find an IT job (either remote or Hybrid) in the Philippines.

What are there any chances of getting remote I.T jobs or freelance jobs in the Philippines?
How should I prepare ahead?

Comment: As this is about long term move rather than short term travel, this would be slightly more appropriate for https://expatriates.stackexchange.com but even there I don’t think it’s on-topic.

Comment: can't you do freelancing to Nigerian clients?

Comment: There are no clear opportunities in Nigeria for freelancing for Nigerian clients.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel but about a job.